# How can I add an additional DocumentRoot to my Apache Server?

Tags: apache

So I have my default htdocs folder, but I would like to add an additional one, which is outside. My problem is that I don't have any idea, how I can do this. I'm only knowing, how I can change the directory, but that's not the way, I would like to go.

I've read something about an Virtual Host, which can be added. So I tried it, but with any result, but haven't expected, that it would be that easy... even the httpd.exe said, that the syntax was ok. But there wasn't any further explanation, how I could go on.

Does anyone know, how I can add an additional one?

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a different [`DocumentRoot` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) to each [Virtual Host section](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) then you have a different document root for each virtual host.

Comment: The issue is another one, I'm already failing by setting the virtual host up. I read also something about, that you need to add another ip in the host file of your OS